# Unity OnMouseDrag too fast drag issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, sprite, draggable, drag

I have two sprites and I am rotating them on mouse drag. When I rotate one, another has to rotate also but a bit slower. The issue is when I move first sprite too fast. I guess Unity skips some points where I ask for current rotation of object. Here is the code:

```
    if(objekatKliknut=="Minute"){
        mouseClickPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 dir = mouseClickPos - transform.position;
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y,dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        angle-=90;
        if (angle < 0.0f) angle += 360.0f;
        angle = Mathf.Round(angle/6.0f)*6.0f;
        if(angle==360) angle=0;
        hand1.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
        a1=angle;
        if(a1!=a2){
            float x = Mathf.Abs(a1-a2);
            if(a1>a2){
            moveRight = false;
                if(x==6){
                    handRot+=addAngle*x/6f;
                    globeRot-=addGlobeAngle;
                }
                a2=a1;
            }
            else if(a1<a2){
            moveRight = true;
                if(x==6){
                    handRot-=addAngle*(x/6f);
                    globeRot+=addGlobeAngle*(x/6f);                     
                }
                a2=a1;
            }
        }
        hand.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(handRot, Vector3.forward);
        oblaci.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(globeRot, Vector3.forward);
    }
```

hand1 is first object that I am rotating, and hand is the second one that needs to be rotated relative to the first one.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: maybe try http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html

Comment: I don't think that will work. How will I determine what is start and what is end position if I drag it fast from point one to point two, and after that immediately to point three?
Problem is in that `x==6` because I rotate object for 6 degrees, and when I move the mouse fast enough `Update()` can't read it fast enough and object rotates for more then 6 degrees.